# Associated records

Tags: sql

I'm pretty new to SQL. I'm trying to write a query that will grab records associated that share an value with the sought after record in a single query.

For example below, if one record has a 'No' in it, I want it to to then return all records that share a common 'Letter'

```
Letter;Present
A;Yes
A;No
A;Yes
B;Yes
B;Yes
B;Yes
```

Returning:

```
Letter;Present
A;Yes
A;No
A;Yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a subquery for that..

```
SELECT a.letter, a.present
FROM yourTable a
WHERE a.letter IN (SELECT letter
                   FROM yourTable
                   WHERE present = 'No');
```

What you do here is select all letters where `present = 'NO'` then you simply re-select from that group where your letter is in the list of letter that contains a `No`.

In other words, the subquery is a filter.

Answer (score 1):

Use a sub-query to find those No letters. Then search for rows where values first character is in the found No letters.

```
select * from table
where letter in (select letter from table where present = 'No');
```

Comment: This might not work on case sensitive DBMS, OP's filter values is 'No' not 'NO'

Comment: Oops, didn't notice. Maybe it's a case insensitive collation? (Will edit anyway. Thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `EXISTS` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM yourTable t2
              WHERE t1.Letter = t2.Letter
              AND t2.Present = 'No')
```

The subquery will get every record with `Present = No`.
The main query will get every record that share the `Letter` value with a result from the subquery.